# Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister. NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm developing a web application using Spring boot and Hibernate with Tomcat8.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225) ~[tomcat8-catalina-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat8-catalina-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754) ~[tomcat8-catalina-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
    ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:382) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass3(DefineClassHelper.java:151) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass2(DefineClassHelper.java:134) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:95) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:131) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:530) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:515) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:451) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:422) ~[javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
        ... 90 common frames omitted
```

This is my only Entity class:

```
    package blablabla.server.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant")
public class Restaurant{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    public Restaurant() {}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

i know there's a lot of questions with the same error. But nothing works on my case.

No typo on my getter/setter.
There's already a no-argument constructor on my Entity.
javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar is on my blabla.war

NB: it's a Java8 webApp. On my unix system there's a jdk11 installed. I've already tried to change my jdk version to 8, but the error is still there.

What i can do?

PS: Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.blabla</groupId>
    <artifactId>blabla_backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Blabla_backend</name>
    <description>First try of Blabla server app!</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <swagger.version>2.7.0</swagger.version>

        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2 Connector (for test only) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Giast necessary for tomcat8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <finalName>Blabla_backend</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It's related to dependencies. Please check out them

Comment: Yep, please post in all of your dependencies in your pom or gradle file. It is generally a dependency issue

Comment: Question updated. @Dylan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Java11 was the problem. As i said, had change my jkd version from 11 to 8, but my tomcat instance was still ponting to Java11.

Comment: Had exactly the same problem! Thanks for sharing the answer! Would have wasted a lot of time otherwise! I think you should accept your own answer as 'the answer'.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seems as if all the correct dependencies are there. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the way you have your ID defined as an Integer rather than an int.

Try changing it to an int value rather than defining it as an Integer object and see if that works. Remember to change your constructor, getters and setters